# How to apply the same theme in all WPF windows using MahApps.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, mahapps.metro

I'm newer with WPF projects and I have a question about the component MahApps.Metro.
I created a MainWindow and other windows in my project, my question is: How to apply the same theme in MainWindow to the others windows of the project? And, I must to apply the ResourceDictionary for all windows or exist any way to do this one time only?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

In your `App.xaml`, set the `ResourceDictionary` property like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Notice that in order for the styles in your resource dictionary to be applied to all controls of that type, the style **should NOT have a key**. For example, a style defined like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="This is the default button text"/>
</Style>
```

In the `ResourceDictionary` will cause all the buttons in the project to have a default value when you create them.

Answer (score 1):

Resource's in WPF work based on their available "scope". [Check this article for a detailed explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/03/creating-and-consuming-resource-dictionaries-in-wpf-and-silverlight.aspx#resources)

Now `Application`(App.xaml) is in a higher scope to `Window`. Thus to share these MahApps control resources across your `Window`'s just move the `ResourceDictionary`'s to the `Application.Resources` scope

something like:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
      <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now you no longer need to add these Dictionary's in each Window as they are available implicitly

Comment: I did exactly this, but didn't work. Some controls, like tab control not work nicely.

Comment: @EvandroAraújo that was just an example. As long as you move **your** used MahApps resources which you have in the `Window` scope to the Application scope, it will be fine. If it's not put together a sample that produces the issue and maybe attach it to your question cos it'd hard to say what it is without seeing any code.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, but, I think I'm not explaining exactly what I want. So, anyway, I'll find a way to do what I want to do. Thank you.